# Bitmeter started on server, can't connect remotely

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I installed [Bitmeter](http://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeteros-downloads) on Ubuntu server and followed the [instructions](https://codebox.net/pages/bitmeteros-faq) in the FAQ. I Issued `bmdb webremoteadmin` and `sudo bmdb webstart` and both command seems successful but It will give an empty response:

[image]

```
sudo bmdb webremoteadmin
```

> BitMeter OS v0.7.6 Copyright © 2014 Rob Dawson Licenced under the GNU
> General Public License
>
> Administrative remote access to the web interface is already enabled

```
sudo bmdb webstart
```

> BitMeter OS v0.7.6 Copyright © 2014 Rob Dawson Licenced under the GNU
> General Public License
>
> Starting BitMeter Web Interface daemon: bmws.

```
sudo bmdb capstart
```

> BitMeter OS v0.7.6 Copyright © 2014 Rob Dawson Licenced under the GNU
> General Public License
>
> Starting BitMeter Capture daemon: bmcapture.

```
more /var/log/bitmeter/bitmeter.log
```

> 2021-04-18 19:53:51 WEB Method not allowed:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

The address must be `http://192.168.0.100:2605/index.html`

`http://192.168.0.100:2605/` alone won't do it.

They should put it their website.